# По какой формуле рассчитывается среднее значение нагрузки ЦП в Linux?

Tags: linux, unix

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает, по какой формуле рассчитывается средние значения, взятые отсюда:

```
uptime
```

> 22:46:39 up 10:35,  1 user,  load average: 2.54, 2.08, 1.91

Comment: Это очень большая тема для изысканий https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9001

Comment: Это среднее количество процессов, которые исполняются +  готовых к исполнению (ждущих процессора в очереди планировщика) подсчитанное за последние 1, 5 и 15 минут. Я думаю, что сумма всех замеров делится на количество замеров

Comment: @Hellseher, ответ на основе ссылки не хочешь написать?

Comment: @Fat-Zer попробую, там достаточно массивные изыскания приводятся.

Comment: @Hellseher, там по большей части пространные объяснения... можно всё в пару-тройку абзацев всё уложить... кстати, в bsd ровным счётом тоже самое: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341696/how-is-load-average-calculated-on-freebsd